# I have this node.js cloud function but it does not work?

Tags: node.js, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this cloud function using node.js that listen every time a child is added on a specific node, then it sends a notification to the users. However when I added something on the database, it does not send anything. I am working on android studio java. Should I connect the function to the android studio, if it will only listen on the database and then send FCM messages on the device tokens.

also how to do debugging on this, I am using VS code.

This is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.listen = functions.database.ref("/Emergencies/{pushId}")
.onCreate(async (change, context) => {
 change.after.val();
 context.params.pushId;

// Get the list of device notification tokens. Note: There are more than 1 users in here
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
  .ref("/Registered Admins/{uid}/Token").once("value");

// The snapshot to the user's tokens.
let tokensSnapshot;

// The array containing all the user's tokens.
let tokens;

const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]);
tokensSnapshot = results[0];

// Check if there are any device tokens.
if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
return functions.logger.log(
  'There are no notification tokens to send to.'
);
}
functions.logger.log(
  'There are',
  tokensSnapshot.numChildren(),
  'tokens to send notifications to.'
);

// Notification details.
const payload = {
notification: {
    title: "New Emergency Request!",
    body: "Someone needs help check Emergenie App now!",
  }
}; 

// Listing all tokens as an array.
tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
// Send notifications to all tokens.
const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
// For each message check if there was an error.
const tokensToRemove = [];
response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
  const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      functions.logger.error(
        'Failure sending notification to',
        tokens[index],
       error
      );
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
      }
    }
 });
  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
});
```

Comment: You've been asking the same "my use-case doesn't work" type question for a few days now, and it's hard to help with. "it does not send anything" is way too late in the process.You should do this debugging, and then tell us the result (if you still need help after that).

Comment: To debug this problem, find the **first** step that fails, not the last one. So: 1) Does the Cloud Function get invoked at all when you write to the database? E.g. if you log a fixed string in its first line, does that string show up in the logging output? 2) Does the `results` that you get from `getDeviceTokensPromise` have the value of the token(s) you expect?

Comment: Until you do your own debugging, all we can do is spot the first problem we find in your code, which is what I did for your earlier questions and what I will do again below. Only once you debug your own problem, and tell us the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do, can we effectively answer the question - which then hopefully allows you to get closer to implementing the use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems wring:

```
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
  .ref("/Registered Admins/{uid}/Token").once("value");
```

The `{uid}` in this string is not defined anywhere, and is also going to be treated as just a string, rather than the ID of a user - which is what I expect you want.

More likely, you'll need to:

1. Load all of `/Registered Admins`
2. Loop over the results you get from that
3. Get the `Token` value for each of them

If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the easiest way to learn it. I recommend first using the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process or with the emulator suite, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to port that code to your Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll follow the resources you suggest!